# Lightbox works locally but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I still consider myself a beginner with CSS and jQuery. I recently discovered lightbox and it's perfect for my assignment. I'm really happy with the way it turned out, but after uploading it to surge, it stopped working properly. Instead, the console give's me this error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2lightbox.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
lightbox.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I originally thought it was the order I included the css and js file in my html. In my head tags I have...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

and at the bottom of my body tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If you want to see the site for yourself: dres-wknd.project3.surge.sh/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you have node_modules online ..

Comment: It is not finding the file, so the path might have changed or judging by the name node_modules you did not do an install on your server

Comment: I think you didn't added lightbox dependencies in   package.json

Comment: @ashishsingh I'm assuming I do just bc I uploaded everything in my homework-1 folder which contains the node_modules folder.

Comment: @Chris my homework-1 folder contains everything for this project. In my terminal, I went to that directory and did `npm install lightbox2 --save` which installed the node_modules to that folder. I didn't see any instructions on how to install it to the server and doing a google search didn't really clear that up for me. What do you recommend? Thanks btw!

Comment: Just copy the `node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js` and the `node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.min.css` next to your `main.css` and change the links. Also, make some thumbnails for your photos, the page takes ages to load.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos i did exactly that just before you responded and it worked! i'll work on making those thumbnails next for sure. thanks!